# awk add word before each uniq pattern based on column number 4

Tags: awk, pattern-matching, addition

hello how i will at begin and end of every each new pattern in column $4 in a file for specified in desired output
number of lines all the time differ along with diff. OS types in column $4

this not worked for me

```
awk -v RS= '{$0 = "OS_PLATFORM_VALID_BEGIN\n" $4 "\nOS_PLATFORM_VALID_END"} 1'file
awk -v RS= '{$0 = "OS_PLATFORM_VALID_BEGIN\n" $1" "$2" "$3 $4" "$5 " "$6" "$7" "$8" "$9"\nOS_PLATFORM_VALID_END"} 1' file
```

this not worked for me above

```
LIB SITE A LINUX X64 DC58 ROOM DC LOC 2.b
LIB SITE A LINUX X64 DC58 ROOM DC LOC 2.b
LIB SITE A OPENV X64 DC22 ROOM DC LOC 2.b
LIB SITE A OPENV X64 DC22 ROOM DC LOC 2.b
LIB SITE A OPENV X64 DC22 ROOM DC LOC 2.b
LIB SITE A WIN9K X64 DC22 ROOM DC LOC 2.b
LIB SITE A WIN9K X64 DC22 ROOM DC LOC 2.b
LIB SITE A WIN9K X64 DC22 ROOM DC LOC 2.b
LIB SITE A WIN9K X64 DC22 ROOM DC LOC 2.b
LIB SITE B RHEL X64 DC10 ROOM DE LOC 3.ma
LIB SITE B RHEL X64 DC10 ROOM DE LOC 3.ma
LIB SITE B RHEL X64 DC10 ROOM DE LOC 3.ma
LIB SITE B RHEL X64 DC10 ROOM DE LOC 3.ma
LIB SITE B SUSE X64 DC10 ROOM DE LOC 3.ma
LIB SITE B SUSE X64 DC10 ROOM DE LOC 3.ma
LIB SITE B SUSE X64 DC10 ROOM DE LOC 3.ma
LIB SITE B SUSE X64 DC10 ROOM DE LOC 3.ma
LIB SITE A LINUX X64 DC41 ROOM DF LOC 5.p
LIB SITE A LINUX X64 DC41 ROOM DF LOC 5.p
LIB SITE A LINUX X64 DC41 ROOM DF LOC 5.p
LIB SITE A LINUX X64 DC41 ROOM DF LOC 5.p
LIB SITE A OPENV X64 DC41 ROOM DF LOC 5.p
LIB SITE A OPENV X64 DC41 ROOM DF LOC 5.p
LIB SITE A OPENV X64 DC41 ROOM DF LOC 5.p
```

this how it should look like:

```
OS_PLATFORM_VALID_BEGIN
LIB SITE A LINUX X64 DC58 ROOM DC LOC 2.b
LIB SITE A LINUX X64 DC58 ROOM DC LOC 2.b
OS_PLATFORM_VALID_END
OS_PLATFORM_VALID_BEGIN
LIB SITE A OPENV X64 DC22 ROOM DC LOC 2.b
LIB SITE A OPENV X64 DC22 ROOM DC LOC 2.b
LIB SITE A OPENV X64 DC22 ROOM DC LOC 2.b
OS_PLATFORM_VALID_END
OS_PLATFORM_VALID_BEGIN
LIB SITE A WIN9K X64 DC22 ROOM DC LOC 2.b
LIB SITE A WIN9K X64 DC22 ROOM DC LOC 2.b
LIB SITE A WIN9K X64 DC22 ROOM DC LOC 2.b
LIB SITE A WIN9K X64 DC22 ROOM DC LOC 2.b
OS_PLATFORM_VALID_END
OS_PLATFORM_VALID_BEGIN
LIB SITE B RHEL X64 DC10 ROOM DE LOC 3.ma
LIB SITE B RHEL X64 DC10 ROOM DE LOC 3.ma
LIB SITE B RHEL X64 DC10 ROOM DE LOC 3.ma
LIB SITE B RHEL X64 DC10 ROOM DE LOC 3.ma
OS_PLATFORM_VALID_END
OS_PLATFORM_VALID_BEGIN
LIB SITE B SUSE X64 DC10 ROOM DE LOC 3.ma
LIB SITE B SUSE X64 DC10 ROOM DE LOC 3.ma
LIB SITE B SUSE X64 DC10 ROOM DE LOC 3.ma
LIB SITE B SUSE X64 DC10 ROOM DE LOC 3.ma
OS_PLATFORM_VALID_END
OS_PLATFORM_VALID_BEGIN
LIB SITE A LINUX X64 DC41 ROOM DF LOC 5.p
LIB SITE A LINUX X64 DC41 ROOM DF LOC 5.p
LIB SITE A LINUX X64 DC41 ROOM DF LOC 5.p
LIB SITE A LINUX X64 DC41 ROOM DF LOC 5.p
OS_PLATFORM_VALID_END
OS_PLATFORM_VALID_BEGIN
LIB SITE A OPENV X64 DC41 ROOM DF LOC 5.p
LIB SITE A OPENV X64 DC41 ROOM DF LOC 5.p
LIB SITE A OPENV X64 DC41 ROOM DF LOC 5.p
OS_PLATFORM_VALID_END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "OS_PLATFORM_VALID_BEGIN"} 
    { if (!seen[$4]++ && NR>1) { 
        print "OS_PLATFORM_VALID_END" ORS "OS_PLATFORM_VALID_BEGIN" } 
    }1;
    END{print "OS_PLATFORM_VALID_END"}' file > outfile
```

See the [online `awk` demo](https://ideone.com/644owW)

**Details**

- `BEGIN{print "OS_PLATFORM_VALID_BEGIN"}` - at the start of the script execution, prints `OS_PLATFORM_VALID_BEGIN`
- `{ if (!seen[$4]++ && NR>1) { print "OS_PLATFORM_VALID_END" ORS "OS_PLATFORM_VALID_BEGIN" } }1` - if there is a unqiue occurrence of Field 4 value and it is not a first line, print `OS_PLATFORM_VALID_END` and `OS_PLATFORM_VALID_BEGIN` lines, else, just print the line (`1` at the end is the default line output triggering construct)
- `END{print "OS_PLATFORM_VALID_END"}` - the `OS_PLATFORM_VALID_END` is printed at the end of the script.

Comment: Stribizew, thank you it almost working but its doubling some lines and its not as i exactly need see for full test i did https://ideone.com/LD1Pqe

Comment: @da4fdsa6 What if you sort the lines first? See https://ideone.com/Lukk2O

Comment: Stribizew, wiktor i am facing one issue if i will even sort them out as you mentioned, i added one column more to have you see that its doubling me even if i will add to column $3 value word "os=" i assumed it will consider whole eg. os=Linux as one uniq pattern , see in my helper column for example for value "LIB SITE A os=OPENV X64 DC22 ROOM DC LOC 2.b 0xe3" its there twice with rest of them 1st block is okay for os=LINUX, see https://ideone.com/KJ790G

Comment: a bit adjusted like this and it works
 awk 'BEGIN{print "OS_PLATFORM_VALID_BEGIN"} { if (!seen[$4]++ && NR>1) { print "OS_PLATFORM_VALID_END" ORS "OS_PLATFORM_VALID_BEGIN" } }1 ;END{print "OS_PLATFORM_VALID_END"}' file1

Comment: @da4fdsa6 Sorry, I understand now, I had a typo, I left `$0` in the main loop.